# Search tips for Facebook

Tags: facebook, search

I'd like to do a search for video's that a friend posted, I've spent 15 minutes manually searching through their posts' and I still haven't found it.

Can I filter out everything but video links?

Any other advanced search tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Type your search into the top search box then click the "See More Results" button at the bottom. Then on the left side of the screen select "Posts By Friends". Then there is a drop down box at the top of the screen labeled "Show". Select "Video" from that to see only Videos posted by friends.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this out, unfortunately it can't search on a specific friend and seems to limit the results of the search

Comment: @Nathan try `[search term]+` Friend's name  or try the `http://www.facebook.com/posted.php?id=[id-number of friend]` - this will filter at least links for you.